# How to set a TextBox value with a button click in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui, reactivex

I am trying to get a handle on ReaxtiveX/ReaxtiveUI and tried to make a really simple program; a TextBox, a TextBlock, and a Button. I want the TextBox to have an initial value and whatever is typed in the TextBox to show in the TextBlock. When the button is clicked, the text in the TextBox will be changed, and therefore so will the text in the TextBlock. I got the TextBlock to update just fine, but can't get the button to work.

Here's my code

**MainWindowViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    //private string _inputText;
    //public string InputText
    //{
    //    get => _inputText;
    //    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _inputText, value);
    //}

    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _inputText;
    public string InputText => _inputText.Value;

    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _copyText;
    public string CopyText => _copyText.Value;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, string> ChangeInputText { get; }
        
    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        //InputText = "Starting Text";
        _inputText = ChangeInputText.ToProperty(this, nameof(InputText), "Starting Text");

        _copyText = this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.InputText)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .Select(x => x.ToUpperInvariant())
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .WhereNotNull()
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.CopyText);

            ChangeInputText = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, string>(_ => { return "Text Changed"; });
    }        
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.InputText, v => v.testTextBox.Text).DisposeWith(d);

            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.CopyText, v => v.copyTextBlock.Text).DisposeWith(d);

            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.ChangeInputText, v => v.changeButton).DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Border Padding="5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="testTextBox"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        <Button x:Name="changeButton"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="5"
                Content="Change Text" />
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <TextBlock x:Name="copyTextBlock" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I started with `InputText` as a property and set the initial value in the ViewModel ctor (before I tried to implement the button command). It worked, with the TextBox having an initial value, and its contents mirrored in the TextBlock. When I tried to implement the button command I changed `InputText` to an OAPH because, as far as I know, you cant use properties with `ToProperty()`.

Now when I run the project I get this
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here is the working ViewModel after Glenn Watson helped me.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    //Made Imput text a property instead of an OAPH
    private string _inputText;
    public string InputText
    {
        get => _inputText;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _inputText, value);
    }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _copyText;
    public string CopyText => _copyText.Value;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, string> ChangeInputText { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        InputText = "Starting Text";
        ChangeInputText = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, string>(_ => { return "Text Changed"; });//.BindTo(this, x => x.InputText);
        ChangeInputText.BindTo(this, x => x.InputText); //Added BindTo

    _copyText = this
        .WhenAnyValue(x => x.InputText)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
        .Select(x => x.ToUpperInvariant())
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .WhereNotNull()
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.CopyText);  
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChangeInputText` RxCommand hasn't been created at the time you did `ToProperty()`. Move it underneath your `ReactiveCommand.Create(` call.

Comment: I moved the ```ToProperty()``` under the ```ReactiveCommand.Create()``` call and got a ```NullReferenceException```. I figure this is because ```_inputText``` is being called in the ```_copyText``` assignment. So I moved ```ReactiveCommand.Create()``` to the top of the ctor, then ```_inputText``` assignment then ```_copyText``` assignment. Now it runs but when I type in the TextBox I get a "System.ArgumentException: 'Property set method not found.'" runtime error.

Comment: OAPH are "read-only" based properties so that's likely your issue there.

Comment: So if you're wanting a mutable property you could use the BindTo() operator on the RxCommand, and then do a get/set combination with RaiseAndSetIfChanged -- that will make it so the text changes based on the command but you can still change the control with your TextBox

Comment: Ok, this is making me feel a bit stupid. I made```InputText``` a property again using ```RaisAndSetIfChanged()```. I tried ```ChangeInputText = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, string>(_ => { return "Text Changed"; }).BindTo(this, x => x.InputText);```, but I get an error saying can't convert IDisposable to RxCommand. With ```this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ChangeInputText).BindTo(this, x => x.InputText);``` my TextBox is set to "ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`2[System.Reactive.Unit,System.String]" and the button doesnt work but what I type in the TextBox is still mirrored to the TextBlock.

Comment: Do the BindTo on a separate line

Comment: Thank you That worked. I'll edit my post to show the working code for anyone that is interested.